# Two trivial questions about zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

I have two questions concerning the Riemann zeta function which are rather trivial so if anyone can give me the answers that would be nice, here is what I`m interested in:

**1)** In the equality $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {1}{n^s}$ is the term $\dfrac {1}{n^s}$ by the definition equal to $e^{-s\log n}$, where $e$ is the natural logarithm base and $\log$ is the natural logarithm?

**2)** Because it is the case that it holds that $\zeta (s)={\dfrac {1}{1-2^{1-s}}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac {(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$ is finding the zero of $\zeta (s)$ in the range $0<\Re(s)<1$ equivalent to finding the zero of $\eta (s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac {(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$ in the same range?

Comment: I don't get it: if your questions are "trivial", what in the world are you asking them for?! And btw: yes, they are trivial...for whoever has studied a little of this stuff, one of the most beautiful in mathematics out there.

Comment: @ DonAntonio I meant trivial in the way that for someone who studied this area. as you say, surely they would be trivial to him. And thank you for not answering them.

Comment: Darn, I was hoping your "trivial question" was going to be "where are all the points where $\zeta(s)$ vanishes?"

Comment: @DonAntonio: Someone can know that something may be trivial for others, but fail to see why at present.

Comment: @Christopher A. Wong :-D In order to go in that way surely I need to know the answer of these two questions! ;-D

Comment: Why in the world you people choose not to tell me the answer?

Comment: @MITjanitor, I don't think you even believe that is true...anyway, writing "I've a trivial question for you, guys" is not, imo, aproper way to ask.

Comment: @DonAntonio *Whoever sows injustice will reap calamity, and the rod of his fury will fail.* You should remember that.

Comment: That's nice, @Thus, yet I'd rather use in this opportunity the following one: " *Make your ear attentive to wisdom and incline your heart to understanding*..." Proverbs 2:2

Comment: @DonAntonio That`s also nice! Okay, we could cite it all night long so better not. I just was dissapointed when you didn´t want to tell me the answers, that´s all.

Comment: Ok @Thus, and now I shall offer you my apologies for that: it's just that I wanted to make a point about the way the question was phrased. In my ears it sounded like "luring" us to address and answer your question.

Comment: I accept your apologies and hope that in the future you will be aware that I am not an expert in mathematics and although my questions may be trivial for someone who have more knowledge than me they need not be trivial to me, and if the question was inappropriate I apologize and will try in the future to raise well-posed questions, okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

To offer a different perspective: while $\dfrac1{n^s}$ is generally equal by definition to $\dfrac1{e^{s\ln n}}$ and the function $e^t$ is a bit more canonical in some sense than the general power function, it doesn't really do any specific good to rework the definition.  In particular, it doesn't expand the domain of convergence of the series at all; both series are defined for $\Re(s)\gt 1$ and neither is convergent outside this domain.  Instead, to extend the domain of definition of the zeta function (and in particular to define it on the *critical strip* $0\lt \Re(s)\lt 1$), analytic continuation is used, for instance via the $\eta$-function you raise in point 2.

Comment: Thank you Steven! I still didn`t have complex analysis at my college so I raised the question to at least have a vague feeling of "what could Riemann zeta be"? I know some rudiments such as the function $f(z)=z^n$ and $f(z)=z^{1/n}$ and a little bit more so actually I am in some sort of process of "going into the complex analysis".  Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Eta function You mention is defined in $\Re s >0$ by the series You mention. Yes, zeta roots are also the roots of eta. Converse does not stand, because eta has some extra roots on line $\Re s =1$.

A friendly note: series for eta converges conditionally only. This means, if one rearranges terms of the series, the result will change, and the sum will not necessarily be eta nor need to converge at all. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem, for instance.

Yes, the usual real logarithm is fine.

Regards.